# PHP, node, python Hosting Server

Tags: hosting

I want to run php, node files on a hosting server. And the node file runs the python script. it means the hosting server should have the python interpreter. Which hosting server supports all these? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Shared hosting may not offer all these services at one place. You can easily use **VPS** and **Cloud Servers** like DigitalOcean, Linode, AWS and GCE they have smaller plans like 10$/ mon which you can easily avail to host any applications. The best thing is you can create complete stack according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is not talking about products, like digitaloecel, linode, aws, e-padi.com, and etc.

But this is talking about the additional features that are support on your server.
The easiest way is, you install OS CloudLinux + cPanel on your server whether it's a vps or a dedicated server, then you can activate the Python, nodeJS, CageFS, and others features via WHM (cPanel admin panel).